# Is it acceptable to post a bounty on the question to raise awareness of your own answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty, incorrect-answers

I just posted an answer where:

- The question is 3 year old
- The main accepted answer has 30+ upvotes
- However, the answer was heavily (50% to 100%) invalidated canonically by EU material published after the answer was posted.
- I posted the correct answer.

Is it acceptable to post a bounty on a question (and award to my own answer) to highlight it and draw attention to the correct info?

<sub>I'm going to assume that the poster of the accepted answer won't be so kind as to delete his own 30+ answer just so we don't have incorrect information shadowing out the correct one :)</sub>

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't award your own bounty to your own answer, and since the accepted answer has more than 2 votes, it will wind up with 50% of your bounty if you don't assign it to someone else's answer.

Comment: @Beofett I'm pretty sure that's not how the auto-assigning if bounties works. To qualify, it needs to be a post made after the bounty started, and which then got a net of 2 up votes or more.

Comment: @Keen Oops.  Misread the help center.  You are correct: the highest scoring answer posted **after** the bounty with 2 or more net upvotes.  However, I'm still pretty sure you can't assign the bounty to yourself, and in any case DVK already posted the answer, so it wouldn't be eligible anyway.  So, in this case, it would be wasted unless someone else also posted a new answer

Comment: @Beofett - well, it would attract attention to the Q&A, even without being awarded. Then again, attracting attention to Q&A for now got the now-incorrect answer 5-6 new upvotes :(

Comment: Have you asked the OP to consider withdrawing the acceptance? Have you asked the existing accepted answerer to consider deleting their (wrong) answer?

Comment: @Richard yes and sort of, respectively

Comment: @DVK - And what happened?

Comment: @Richard - OP changed the acceptabce. Other answer wasn't deleted (nor did I really want it to be). OTOH, the fact that the other answer picked up 8 NEW FRESH upvotes since I posted my answer AND a comment indicating that answer is no longer correct (and the answer wasn't any great quality - no canon quotes or references), is extremely troubling.

Comment: @dvk - I find it most annoying when you find an old question, post a well-sourced answer that canonically answers that question and are then forced to languish below an older incorrect answer just because it came first. I take solace that over time, the "right" answer will usually gain more votes, especially if you keep adding to it, in order to periodically bump it.

Comment: As long as the accepted answer is switched, I see no problem with that. I mean, this voting system is all wrong anyway, but within its (flawed) context, switching acceptance seems like the best result.

Answer (score 10):

Consensus on meta.stackexchange.com seems to indicate that [yes, you can use bounties to draw attention to your own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234528/166646).

There was concern about this being used as a way to game the system, by gambling reputation in the hopes of earning enough upvotes on a late answer to make a net gain, but this [has been addressed by setting increasing minimum bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/166646)

> As noted by Robert, this has come up recently. Posting a bounty is a perfectly reasonably thing, a good thing (with badges too!). However, when applied repeatedly to a question it does start to represent abuse.
>
> To help minimise this, but while leaving open the option of offering a subsequent bounty when you really, really are looking for another option we will be implementing a change here, where subsequent bounties have a higher minimum offering. This means you can't place 6 "cheap" bounties of 50 rep, to keep your answer on the bounty board to get lots of pass-by upvotes, as subsequent bounties probably1 will not cover your "spend".

Also:

> Another related change [has been mentioned by Sam Saffron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/134300):
>
> - If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is **100**

Comment: The risk seems to be, if I post a bounty to draw attention to my (better) answer, will I incur heavy downvoting for looking like a rep-whore.